# Regex for matches but does not match?

Tags: regex

How can I get a regex to match anything matching

```
[2-9][0-9][0-9]
```

but not matching

```
303|719|720|970
```

For example, the regex should match 406, but not 719 (as it matches the second regex) or 3333 (as it does not match the first regex).

Comment: Depending on the context, you might find it easier to write and maintain two separate regexes and work with two passes: first match then exclude.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you would use a negative lookahead and anchors:

```
^(?!303|719|720|970)[2-9][0-9][0-9]$
```

That should prevent the numbers within the negative lookahead to match while matching all that the first regex in your question matches.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/lH5yH1)

And usually, if you want to improve the speed of a regex where there are many alternations, you can make merge some, but you might lose some readability (the below is one way to do that):

```
^(?!303|7(?:19|20)|970)[2-9][0-9][0-9]$
```